# linear gradient diagonal shadow

Tags: css

I am attempting to add a shadow to the diagonally cut section of the div. Please see code below. Unfortunately, I am unable to do so, and can only get a box-shadow around the whole div. How can I target the diagonal section? Where the left hand side div meets Hulk Hogan, I want to include a shadow here. I hope this makes sense.

[See jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0d6b37t4/)

```css
.left-box {
  float: left;
  height: 361px;
  width: 68%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

.right-box {
  right: 0;
  height: 361px;
  width: 55%;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("http://img.bleacherreport.net/img/images/photos/002/796/309/8288d50f6769ccb555f2b9010a4f6544_crop_north.jpg?w=543&h=361&q=75");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.gradient{
  position: relative;
}

.gradient.right {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%, yellow 50%) no-repeat, linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 0.1%, yellow 0.1%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 41% 122%, 60% 100%;
  background-position: 100% 0%, 0% 0%;
  box-shadow: red 0 0 50px;
}
.gradient h3{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 40px;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5%;
  width: 50%;
}

.gradient p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient right left-box">
</div>
<div class="right-box box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to try to include it into the gradient:

```css
.gradient.right {
  background: linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%,
    rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 53%, yellow 53.5%) no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 0.1%, yellow 0.1%) no-repeat;
  background-size: 41% 122%, 60% 100%;
  background-position: 100% 0%, 0% 0%;
}
```

With the `rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 50%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 53%` you can specify the color of the shadow (they should be the same values for R, G and B).

The result looks like this:

[image: Expected result.]

Here’s the [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0d6b37t4/1/).

I have chosen a 0.5% increment (from `53%` to `53.5%`) for the gradient from the red shadow to the yellow background so that the edge looks a bit smoother. You can also calculate the values with the CSS3 [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) function for more control.